# android VIewpager How to achieve the bound effect

Tags: android-viewpager, bounce

I google the question many days. Find a solution which is  add a blank View int the first and end  of Viewpager. when viewpager.getcurrentItem()==0,then rePoint to 1. 
In my opinion this approach is very poor。
Because, this solution change the viewpager.getcount(). may cause many problem.

I find a class to hanler this,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/EdgeEffectCompat.html
But I do not know how to use it！
Can someone give me an example?

like that 
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9poNqa96rJyLU5Va0lnMHJGY0k

When I release the finger back to the original position

Comment: bound effect? or bounce effect, what kinda bounce are you looking for, plz elaborate

Comment: The Pic had upload to google doc. you can find it in the question

Comment: OR Like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773565/visual-indication-of-over-scroll-in-android

Comment: you say, the above solution will change `viewpager.getcount()` value. But you can override it to supply value of your choice. Make `getRealCount()` for other cases when you want the real value.

Comment: to do an overscroll-effect like the rubber-band on iOS

Comment: They have a patent on that :P

Answer (score 12):

If anyone still wonders how to do this I actually found a solution based on a brilliant library by renard314: https://github.com/inovex/ViewPager3D
All the credit should go to him :)
Anyways, extends ViewPager:

```
public class BounceBackViewPager extends ViewPager {

/**
 * maximum z distance to translate child view
 */
final static int DEFAULT_OVERSCROLL_TRANSLATION = 150;

/**
 * duration of overscroll animation in ms
 */
final private static int DEFAULT_OVERSCROLL_ANIMATION_DURATION = 400;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final static String DEBUG_TAG = ViewPager.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

/**
 * 
 * @author renard, extended by Piotr Zawadzki
 * 
 */
private class OverscrollEffect {
    private float mOverscroll;
    private Animator mAnimator;

    /**
     * @param deltaDistance [0..1] 0->no overscroll, 1>full overscroll
     */
    public void setPull(final float deltaDistance) {
        mOverscroll = deltaDistance;
        invalidateVisibleChilds(mLastPosition);
    }

    /**
     * called when finger is released. starts to animate back to default position
     */
    private void onRelease() {
        if (mAnimator != null && mAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    startAnimation(0);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }
            });
            mAnimator.cancel();
        } else {
            startAnimation(0);
        }
    }

    private void startAnimation(final float target) {
        mAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "pull", mOverscroll, target);
        mAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        final float scale = Math.abs(target - mOverscroll);
        mAnimator.setDuration((long) (mOverscrollAnimationDuration * scale));
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private boolean isOverscrolling() {
        if (mScrollPosition == 0 && mOverscroll < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        final boolean isLast = (getAdapter().getCount() - 1) == mScrollPosition;
        if (isLast && mOverscroll > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

final private OverscrollEffect mOverscrollEffect = new OverscrollEffect();
final private Camera mCamera = new Camera();

private OnPageChangeListener mScrollListener;
private float mLastMotionX;
private int mActivePointerId;
private int mScrollPosition;
private float mScrollPositionOffset;
final private int mTouchSlop;

private float mOverscrollTranslation;
private int mOverscrollAnimationDuration;

public BounceBackViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
    final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(configuration);
    super.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener());
    init(attrs);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BounceBackViewPager);
    mOverscrollTranslation = a.getDimension(R.styleable.BounceBackViewPager_overscroll_translation, DEFAULT_OVERSCROLL_TRANSLATION);
    mOverscrollAnimationDuration = a.getInt(R.styleable.BounceBackViewPager_overscroll_animation_duration, DEFAULT_OVERSCROLL_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    a.recycle();
}

public int getOverscrollAnimationDuration() {
    return mOverscrollAnimationDuration;
}

public void setOverscrollAnimationDuration(int mOverscrollAnimationDuration) {
    this.mOverscrollAnimationDuration = mOverscrollAnimationDuration;
}

public float getOverscrollTranslation() {
    return mOverscrollTranslation;
}

public void setOverscrollTranslation(int mOverscrollTranslation) {
    this.mOverscrollTranslation = mOverscrollTranslation;
}

@Override
public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mScrollListener = listener;
};

private void invalidateVisibleChilds(final int position) {
     for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
     getChildAt(i).invalidate();

     }
    //this.invalidate();
    // final View child = getChildAt(position);
    // final View previous = getChildAt(position - 1);
    // final View next = getChildAt(position + 1);
    // if (child != null) {
    // child.invalidate();
    // }
    // if (previous != null) {
    // previous.invalidate();
    // }
    // if (next != null) {
    // next.invalidate();
    // }
}

private int mLastPosition = 0;

private class MyOnPageChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mScrollListener != null) {
            mScrollListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }
        mScrollPosition = position;
        mScrollPositionOffset = positionOffset;
        mLastPosition = position;
        invalidateVisibleChilds(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        if (mScrollListener != null) {
            mScrollListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

        if (mScrollListener != null) {
            mScrollListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
        if (state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mScrollPositionOffset = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        final int action = ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK;
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            final int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
            final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, index);
            mLastMotionX = x;
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, index);
            break;
        }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean callSuper = false;

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        callSuper = true;
        mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
        break;
    }
    case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
        callSuper = true;
        final int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
        final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, index);
        mLastMotionX = x;
        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, index);
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        if (mActivePointerId != INVALID_POINTER_ID) {
            // Scroll to follow the motion event
            final int activePointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);
            final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, activePointerIndex);
            final float deltaX = mLastMotionX - x;
            final float oldScrollX = getScrollX();
            final int width = getWidth();
            final int widthWithMargin = width + getPageMargin();
            final int lastItemIndex = getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
            final int currentItemIndex = getCurrentItem();
            final float leftBound = Math.max(0, (currentItemIndex - 1) * widthWithMargin);
            final float rightBound = Math.min(currentItemIndex + 1, lastItemIndex) * widthWithMargin;
            final float scrollX = oldScrollX + deltaX;
            if (mScrollPositionOffset == 0) {
                if (scrollX < leftBound) {
                    if (leftBound == 0) {
                        final float over = deltaX + mTouchSlop;
                        mOverscrollEffect.setPull(over / width);
                    }
                } else if (scrollX > rightBound) {
                    if (rightBound == lastItemIndex * widthWithMargin) {
                        final float over = scrollX - rightBound - mTouchSlop;
                        mOverscrollEffect.setPull(over / width);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                mLastMotionX = x;
            }
        } else {
            mOverscrollEffect.onRelease();
        }
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        callSuper = true;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        mOverscrollEffect.onRelease();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastMotionX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, newPointerIndex);
            callSuper = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    if (mOverscrollEffect.isOverscrolling() && !callSuper) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
    if (child.getWidth() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    final int position = child.getLeft() / child.getWidth();
    final boolean isFirstOrLast = position == 0 || (position == getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
    if (mOverscrollEffect.isOverscrolling() && isFirstOrLast) {
        final float dx = getWidth() / 2;
        final int dy = getHeight() / 2;
        t.getMatrix().reset();
        final float translateX =(float) mOverscrollTranslation * (mOverscrollEffect.mOverscroll > 0 ? Math.min(mOverscrollEffect.mOverscroll, 1) : Math.max(mOverscrollEffect.mOverscroll, -1));
        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.translate(-translateX, 0, 0);
        mCamera.getMatrix(t.getMatrix());
        mCamera.restore();
        t.getMatrix().preTranslate(-dx, -dy);
        t.getMatrix().postTranslate(dx, dy);

        if (getChildCount() == 1) {
            this.invalidate();
        } else {
            child.invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

and add a resources file somewhere in the *values* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="BounceBackViewPager">
    <!--
    determines the maximum amount of translation along the z-axis during the overscroll. 
    Default is 150.
    -->
    <attr name="overscroll_translation" format="dimension" />

    <!-- Duration of animation when user releases the over scroll. Default is 400 ms. -->
    <attr name="overscroll_animation_duration" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

All I had to do was to change the transformation to support translateX. I strongly recommend reading the documentation for ViewPager3D first.

Comment: To add on top of a great answer from Piotr, if someone will have same problem as me (Animator is only available from Api 11) adding this kind of behaviour to Api below 11, you can use another great library - "NineOldAndroids", that exported all this api for animations that were started in Honeycomb, which can be used in effect in apps with min Api 1.

Got an answer from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267291/animation-before-api-11

Comment: Great answer. This only works for me when scrolling left on the first element and it doesn't do this effect scrolling right on the last. Am I missing something?

Comment: I should say that I'm displaying multiple views per page, overriding getPageWidth() in my Adapter to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The BounceBackViewPager  have a bug, when show mutiple multiple pages(fragment) in one page(screen), only the first page have the OverscrollEffect, that is ,you can see multiple pages on screen, only the first page will bounce back, it looks strange. And only the left side have overscrolleffect, the right side haven't have.

my implement is:

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
          return    1/mShowPictureSize; 
}
```